# Compare and exchange weak an atomic variable

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic

I have code (updated to correct the union-struct ordering):

```
union A {
    struct {
         short b;
         short c;
    };

    std::atomic<int> d;
}
```

and I want to swap both b and c (hence the atomic d) with the value zero, using `compare_exchange_weak()`. So I have this:

```
A a;
.
.
.
std::atomic<int32_t> x = a.d.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
int32_t valToReplace = 0;

return a.d.compare_exchange_weak(valToReplace, x, std::memory_order_release, std::memory_order_relaxed);
```

How do I do this? The argument to compare_exchange_weak(), `x`, cannot be atomic- so I am confused?

Comment: I think you have the `struct` and `union` nested in the wrong order. Unioning two `short`s doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Also, `compare_exchange_weak` doesn't take an `atomic` as parameter.

Comment: @Sneftel b and c are supposed to be represented together by d

Comment: So how can I exchange b and c together, atomically?

Comment: That means that `b` and `c` should be in a struct, unioned with `d`.

Answer (score 1):

The local variable `x` shouldn't be atomic. There's no reason for it to be, and it can't be used as the argument to `compare_exchange_weak`, which expects a regular value.

I won't comment on whatever you're trying to do with the union, since that makes no sense to me.

Comment: I got the union the wrong way around. I would like to swap the 32 bits of the two 16-bit variables b and c together, at the same time?

Comment: @user997112: Then be very careful how you access `b` and `c`, since the union bypasses the atomic nature of `d` and makes it very hard to avoid data races. You'd be better off reading `d` atomically, then extracting whichever part of the value you want.

Comment: this struct is stored in another container. Should I just declare the struct as atomic, so atomic<A> and forget the union with an atomic variable?

Comment: @user997112: I'd certainly forget the union. An atomic integer might be better than an atomic struct, as it's more likely to be lock-free.